# Missing files deployed on Test Controller (TFS 2013)

Tags: wpf, azure, tfs, coded-ui-tests

I'm working with the Visual Studio Online. I'm working in a WPF solution. I have a VM in Azure to be able to run the CodedUI tests. I've configured a Standard Environment (Lab Management) and a Test Controller and Test Agent in that machine. I have a test case with a simple CodedUI test (only opens the application) as automation.

When I run the tests manually from the VM (using tcm.exe) I get some errors due to missing dlls (in my case EntityFramework.SqlServer).

I'm seeing that in the directory I specify when running tcm.exe all the files are there, but in the Controller folder (something like C:\Users\TFSTEST\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\106\Deployment) some of the assemblies aren't there. Therefore, I can see in the Test Agent logs that only the assemblies present in that folder are copied to the agent folder. And, for that reason, the tests are not executed.

I've tried to specify some of that files in the deployment section of the Test Case, but it seems that is not working.

What can I do to ensure that all the files present on the build output are copied to the Test Controller data folder?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property "Copy Local" to True for EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Comment: Yes, I set the "Copy Local" to true. As I said, the build output is correct (it has the EF assemblies, but when it copies that folder to the test controller, some dlls are missing. Thanks.

Comment: Is this DLL used for your application? Or just the tests?